# Web Hosting Service throttling/dropping traffic?

Tags: web-hosting, throttling, restrictions

I have had a justHost account now for a couple of years, the service is lame but i cant really argue with the price. I dont run any live sites there currently but i use it for development. I have recently been using it with magento community edition, and initially things were going well but then i ran into problems.

I had some issues with the previous version so i upgraded to 1.6.0, after a few problems i got this working, but kept experiencing problems with errors being thrown when trying to connect to pages. After getting frustrated and leaving it for a few hours I discovered that I could view a few pages this time before it errored.

I couldn't find anything about justHosts bandwidth policy, I have had no luck contacting them. Has anyone else experienced similar problems with a shared hosted service? what sort of cpu throttling and bandwidth policies does your hosting service use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shared hosting by its nature means, you are sharing the resources with other people. It may be that someone else's process is hogging the resources.

As to how they throttle, and if they have a policy. I doubt, they are sophisticated enough. My hunch is they are just another reseller of some main hosting company. The main hosting company might have such constraints in place.

Either ways, I doubt if you can get customer service to unthrottle you.

I have tried several, Dreamhost, JustHost, MochaHost and felt annoyed with each.

Now I host with Rackspace. Their smallest instance costs me about $12/month and I have a complete unix box at my disposal. I wouldn't go anywhere else.

hope it helps.